# How to install application remotely on my client android devices?

Tags: android

Is there any way to remotely deploy/install on the client Android devices?

In case of BlackBerry this could potentially be done using the BES server to remotely deploy the applications.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, this is not possible...

Answer (score 2):

not exactly but you can send a mail attaching .apk file (from bin directory)

Answer (score 0):

to elaborate on Jignesh's answer, it looks like the easiest way to do it is to mail the .apk file to your client. make sure they open their mail on the phone, and when they click on it, then it installs. very late answer i know, but i'm looking into the same thing now. hope it helps someone!